# Disable html escaping inside backticks in python-markdown

Tags: python, markdown

I observed, that python-markdown always escapes HTML entities inside backticks, even with safe=False:

```
In [1]: import markdown

In [2]: markdown.markdown("&amp;")
Out[2]: u'<p>&amp;</p>'

In [3]: markdown.markdown("*&amp;*")
Out[3]: u'<p><em>&amp;</em></p>'

In [4]: markdown.markdown("`&amp;`")
Out[4]: u'<p><code>&amp;amp;</code></p>'
```

Is it a bug or a feature; is there a way to keep HTML entities unchanged?

Answer (score -1):

Backticks [designate a code block](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code), meaning that HTML entities must be escaped so that the code displays correctly, so this isn't a bug. While I don't know why you would want to get around that, and there may be better ways to accomplish your goals, `python-markdown` ignores text inside HTML tags, so perhaps enclosing your HTML entities inside do-nothing HTML would suit your purposes.

```
>>> import markdown
>>> markdown.markdown("<div>`&amp;`</div>")
u'<div>`&amp;`</div>'
```

If you find the `<div>` tags objectionable, you could postprocess them out reasonably simply using a `div` class and an HTML parsing tool like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("<div class='nothing'>`&amp;`</div>")
>>> for div in soup.findAll('div', 'nothing'):
...     div.replaceWithChildren()
>>> print soup
`&amp;`
```

Maybe a bit more complicated than what you initially wanted, but I think this is probably the simplest solution short of fundamentally modifying `python-markdown`.

Comment: It doesn't work for me because I still need backticks changed to "code" blocks. I solved it with a custom markdown extension that restores escaped entities. The better way, I think, would be to not use backticks at all for this case, but I had too much text already marked up this way.

Comment: @pomel, It is 6+ years later but maybe you remember what the extension name was?